# Function keeps echoing final value

Tags: php

I have written a basic function:

```
function letterreplacement() {
    global $word;

    $string = $word;
    $trans = array("a" => "4", "e" => "3", "i" => "1", "o" => "0");

    echo strtr($string, $trans);
}

$myvariable = letterreplacement();
```

The problem I am having is on the last line - it keeps `echo`ing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace echo with return

Comment: you want `return`, not `echo`

Comment: So, if you call echo .. it echos? Why yes, it does. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a global variable and an `echo` statement, your function should take a parameter as input and `return` something as output. (You don't need a `;` after a `}` in PHP, by the way)

Something more like this:

```
        function letterreplacement($string) {

            $trans = array("a" => "4","e"=>"3","i"=>"1","o"=>"0");

            return strtr($string, $trans);

        }

        $myvariable = letterreplacement($word);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have `echo strtr($string, $trans);` in your code, replace it with `return strtr($string, $trans)`

Comment: your echoing the variables out in your code, return them instead as the answer says, then you can do whatever it is you want to do with them later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use return to return the data from your function, echo will send data from the script to browser/screen.

php.net/echo
php.net/return

Answer (score 0):

To return value from method/function you need to use `return` syntax. i.e:

```
function foo() {
  return 2;
}

echo foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just to echo than its called void function , function that does not return value , so you can't initialize variables with that function , but if you want soo , at function body instead of echo you need to use return keyword as follow :

return strtr($string, $trans);